VHDL-clock simulation, 80 ps delay
I am new to VHDL and I created a 25% duty cycle 10 kHz clock from a 100 MHz 50% duty cycle clock, but when I simulate it, there is a 80 ps delay between every rising edge of the clocks. What causes this and how can I fix it?
I created a 10 MHz clock using clocking wizard and added it to my topmodule.
Simulation:

Simulation zoomed out:

topmodule:
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;


entity waveform is
Port (clk_in: in std_logic;
     clk_out: out std_logic );
end waveform;

architecture Behavioral of waveform is
    signal clk_out1 : std_logic;
    signal reset : std_logic;
    signal locked : std_logic;
    signal clk : std_logic:='1';
    signal ctr: integer range 0 to 999:=0;
    
    
    component clk_wiz_0
    port (
        -- Clock in ports
        -- Clock out ports
        clk_out1          : out    std_logic;
        -- Status and control signals
        reset             : in     std_logic;
        locked            : out    std_logic;
        clk_in            : in     std_logic
    );
    end component;

begin
    clk_wiz: clk_wiz_0
    port map ( 
        -- Clock out ports  
        clk_out1 => clk_out1,
        -- Status and control signals                
        reset => reset,
        locked => locked,
        -- Clock in ports
        clk_in => clk_in
    );

    process(clk_out1)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk_out1) then
            ctr <= ctr + 1;
            if ctr = 249 then 
                clk <= not clk;
            elsif ctr = 999 then
                clk <= not clk;
                ctr <= 0;
            end if;
        end if;
  
        clk_out<=clk;
    end process;

end Behavioral;

simulation:
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity testbench_waveform is
end testbench_waveform;

architecture Behavioral of testbench_waveform is
    -- Constants
    constant CLK_PERIOD : time := 10 ns;  

    -- Signals
    signal clk_in : std_logic := '0';  -- Input clock signal
    signal clk_out : std_logic;        -- Output clock signal from the waveform module

    -- Component declaration
    component waveform
        port (
            clk_in : in std_logic;
            clk_out : out std_logic
        );
    end component;

begin
    -- Instantiate the waveform module
    UUT: waveform
    port map (
        clk_in => clk_in,
        clk_out => clk_out
    );

    -- Clock process for generating clk_in
    clk_process: process
    begin
        while now < 100000000 ns loop  -- Simulate for 1000 ns
            clk_in <= not clk_in;  -- Toggle the clock signal
            wait for CLK_PERIOD / 2;  -- Wait for half the clock period
        end loop;
        wait;  -- Wait indefinitely after simulation completes
    end process;

end Behavioral;


Where can we see the 0.1 ns delay between every rising edge of the clocks? Which delay between every rising edge of the clocks did you expect instead?

In the zoomed-in version you can see that rising edge of 10 khz clock is 0.1 ns ahead of 100 mhz clock

You mean it's 80 ps ahead?

yeah sorry it's 80 ps

Are you doing rtl simulation, or a netlist simulation?

I don't know :) I just ran a behavioral simulation

It's likely the clk_wiz component is adding the delay. This is a xilinx IP. If this is the case then this is not a vhdl problem

remove locked signal from clk wizard, use simple mode and report the result

What is the simulation resolution?

There isn’t sufficient information present in your question to replicate the issue. See [ask]
